What is the general minimum amount of black squares in a $9$ by $9$ grid of white squares to not have a single 1 by $x$ line of white squares?
I encountered a problem that asked me to find the minimum amount of black squares needed to replace any white squares in a $9$ by $9$ grid of white squares, so no line of $1$ by $4$ white squares (horizontal or vertical) is in the grid.
I was able to get the problem right (the answer was $20$), but it made me wonder if there was a general strategy to find the minimum amount of black squares needed to not have a single $1$ by $x$ line of white squares in a $9$ by $9$ grid, or maybe even an $n$ by $n$ grid.

This seems to ask for a greedy approach.  Let the upper left corner be white and a $3 \times 3$ square around it.  Make the next squares black to avoid a $1 \times 4$.  Keep going.  Does that get your $20?$  If not, please post your best effort in the question.  Certainly as $n$ gets large there will be a repeating pattern and we can compute the overall density.

@RossMillikan my naive approach is to cycle through putting black squares on $0+rn$ modulo $x$ where $r$ is the row number...

For integers $1\le x\le n$ let $f(n,x)$ denote the minimum number of squares in an $n\times n$ grid that can be painted black so that every $1\times x$ or $x\times1$ rectangle in the grid contains at least one black square. Write $n=qx+r$ where $q=\lfloor n/x\rfloor$. I will show that
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}x\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}x\right\rfloor=\frac{n^2-r^2}x\le f(n,x)\le\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}x\right\rfloor;$$
so in particular $f(n.x)=\lfloor n^2/x\rfloor$ if $r^2\lt x$.
Lower bound. We can pack the $n\times n$ grid with nonoverlapping $1\times x$ and $x\times1$ rectangles which cover the whole grid except for an $r\times r$ corner. The number of those rectangles is $(n^2-r^2)/x$, and each of them must contain a black square.
Upper bound. Number the rows and the columns from $1$ to $n$. For each $k\in\{1,\dots,x\}$ let $S_k$ be the set of all squares $(i,j)$ such that $i+j\equiv k\pmod x$. Then each of the sets $S_k$ hits every $1\times x$ and $x\times1$ rectangle. Choose $k$ so that $|S_k|\le n^2/x$.
When $n=9$:
$f(9,1)=81$
$f(9,2)=40$
$f(9,3)=27$
$f(9,4)=20$
$13\le f(9,5)\le16$ (**)
$12\le f(9,6)\le13$ (*)
$f(9,7)=11$
$f(9,8)=10$
$f(9,9)=9$
(*) Actually $f(9,6)=12$; paint square $(i,j)$ black if $i+j\equiv1\pmod6$.
More generally, if $n=qx+r$ where $0\le r\le x/2$, then $f(n,x)=(n^2-r^2)/x$; paint $(i,j)$ black if $i+j\equiv1\pmod x$.
(**) In fact $f(9,5)=16$. Assume for a contradiction that $15$ black squares hit all the $1\times x$ and $x\times1$ rectangles. Let $m$ be the maximum number of black squares in any row or column; so $2\le m\le7$. Some row or column has $m$ black squares; we may assume it's a row. That leaves $15-m$ black squares for the other $8$ rows, so at most $7-m$ of those rows can have $2$ black squares, and at least $8-(7-m)=m+1$ rows have only $1$ black square. If a row has only $1$ black square, that black square must be the central square of the row. Hence there are at least $m+1$ black squares in the central column, but this contradicts the maximality of $m$.
More generally, if $x\ge2$, then $f(2x-1,x)=4(x-1)$.
Remark. Define $f(n,x)=0$ for $x\gt n$. Suppose $n=qx+r$ where $q=\lfloor n/x\rfloor$.
$$\text{If}\quad4qr+f(n-2r,x)\gt\frac{n^2-r^2}x$$
$$\text{then}\quad f(n,x)\gt\frac{n^2-r^2}x.$$
(Proof left as an exercise.)
Example. Consider $f(11,4)$.
We have $n=11$, $x=4$, $q=2$, $r=3$, $f(n-2r,x)=f(5,4)=6$, so
$$4qr+f(n-2r,x)=30\gt28=\frac{n^2-r^2}x.$$
By the Remark it follows that $f(11,4)\gt28$, i.e., $f(11,4)\ge29$.

So, I guess this is what you are talking about:

... and you are looking for a similar formula for any length $n$ ($n$ not necessarily being equal to $4$).
You will need to base your solution on $\frac{9}{n}$ but beware never to start colouring in a corner, or you might end up with a wrong number (I just arrived at $21$).
